# "exception in thread main java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception" when using an array + for loop

Tags: java, arrays, program-entry-point

when I wrote this code to prompt the user for how many numbers are going to be entered, I got an error saying: "exception in thread main java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception"

PS: note that I used an array of int + for loop to write it.

```js
import java.util.*;
public class Pr8{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    //Prompt the user for how many numbers are going to be entered.
    
    System.out.print("*Please write how many numbers are going to be entered: ");
    int a = scan.nextInt();
    int[] n = new int[a];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++){
      System.out.print("*Please enter an enteger: ");
      n[a] = scan.nextInt();
    }//for
    
  }//main
}//Pr8
```

Comment: that for loob will get you every time ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

`n[a] = scan.nextInt();`

to

`n[i] = scan.nextInt();`

`a` is not a valid index in an array that only has `a` elements. The valid indices are 0 to a-1.

Comment: @Bader ,`n` is the array containing `a` elements with valid indexes of `n` 0 to a-1 and not `a`. This is because array indexes start from 0 not 1

Comment: @Bader You are looping with the `i` variable, so I'm assuming you want to store in each iteration of the loop the new input in the i'th position of the array. You can't store it in the `a`'s position, since there's no such position in the array you created.

Comment: If you want to be able to do n.getElementWithValue(...) use arraylist ( or other list implementation ) then you can just do(with n Arraylist of Strings) n.get("This string")

Comment: @Eran can you please look at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181778/java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-50-handling-big-integers-on-java ///// the program I did is the 9's complement to deal with addition and subtraction in java, but there is some problems with it!!