# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in ten's complement arithmetic implementation

Tags: java, arrays, int

My code tries to implement an algorithm to

- take user input for two integer numbers and an operand `+` or `-` from the console,
- store those numbers digit by digit in an `int[50]`, representing negative ones in [ten's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements#Decimal_example) format,
- implement (decimal) digit-by-digit add/subtract operations,
- print the result in decimal format without leading zeroes.

However, in my current implementation there are two problems

- When adding 99 + 9999, the printed result is 01098 instead of the expected 010098.
- When subtracting 99 - 9999, I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 50` instead of the expected result -09900.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Program9 {
    public static String getOperand() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String stringOfInteger;

        System.out.print("Please enter an integer up to 50 numbers: ");
        stringOfInteger = scan.nextLine();
        return stringOfInteger;
    }

    public static int[] convert(String operand) {
        int[] integer = new int[50];
        char ch;

        int position = operand.length() - 1;
        for (int i = integer.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (position >= 0)
                ch = operand.charAt(position--);
            else
                ch = 0;
            if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
                integer[i] = ch - '0';
            } else {
                integer[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        return integer;
    }

    public static int[] add(int[] operand1, int[] operand2) {
        int[] result = new int[operand1.length];
        int carry = 0;
        for (int i = operand1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            result[i] = operand1[i] + operand2[i] + carry;
            if (result[i] / 10 == 1) {
                result[i] = result[i] % 10;
                carry = 1;
            } else
                carry = 0;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static int[] complement(int[] operand) {
        int[] result = new int[operand.length];
        for (int i = operand.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            result[i] = 9 - operand[i];
        return result;
    }

    public static int[] add1(int[] operand) {
        int[] result = new int[50];
        result[49] = 1;
        for (int i = result.length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
            result[i] = 0;
        return result;
    }

    public static int[] negate(int[] operand) {
        return add(add1(operand), complement(operand));
    }

    public static void print(int[] result, String operation) {
        if (operation.charAt(0) == '+')
            System.out.print("The subtotal of the two integer = ");
        else if (operation.charAt(0) == '-')
            System.out.print("The substraction of the two integers = ");
        if (result[0] == 9) {
            result = negate(result);
            System.out.print("-");
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                if (result[i] == 0 && result[i + 1] == 0)
                    continue;
                else
                    System.out.print(result[i]);
            }
        } else
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                if (result[i] == 0 && result[i + 1] == 0)
                    continue;
                else
                    System.out.print(result[i]);
            }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] result = new int[50];
        String string1 = getOperand();
        String string2 = getOperand();
        int[] integer1 = convert(string1);
        int[] integer2 = convert(string2);
        String operation;

        System.out.print("Please enter which operation will be used (+ or -): ");
        operation = scan.nextLine();
        if (operation.charAt(0) == '+')
            add(integer1, integer2);
        else if (operation.charAt(0) == '-')
            integer2 = negate(integer2);

        result = add(integer1, integer2);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integer1));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integer2));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(add(integer1, integer2)));
        print(result, operation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after so much discussion and so many issues with your code I have totally revised your original code because you said you wanted to learn more. Among other improvements I have done the following changes:

- Meaninfgul class name
- Meaningful method and parameter names
- Convert repeated and often used constants like `50` and the array representation of the number `1` (needed for negation) into static final members for clean code reasons (documentation, easy change in one place, meaningful names), runtime optimisation).
- Extend the code to permit negative integers as operands
- Added validation patterns for user input. E.g. now the maximum number length is checked in order to avoid an array overflow.
- Avoid numeric overflows during calculation by making the array bigger than the maximum number of digits permitted for user input (see source code comments)
- Add retry loops with error handling for operand and operator input, extract console handling into one parametrised method.
- Simplify code by removing unnecessary checks because user input is already validated before converting it into an `int[]`.
- Make debug output optional

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TensComplementArithmetic {
    // Print debug messages?
    private static final boolean DEBUG = true;

    // Maximum length for numbers entered by a user
    // (number of digits excluding the optional +/- sign)
    private static final int MAX_NUMBER_LENGTH = 50;

    // Array must have one additional element for the sign and
    // one more to avoid overflows when adding big negative numbers
    private static final int ARRAY_LENGTH = MAX_NUMBER_LENGTH + 2;

    // Scanner for console input handling
    private static final Scanner INPUT_SCANNER = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Regex pattern for positive/negative integer number format verification incl. length check
    private static final Pattern INTEGER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[+-]?[0-9]{1," + MAX_NUMBER_LENGTH + "}");

    // Regex pattern for operator verification (currently only "+"/"-" allowed)
    private static final Pattern OPERATOR_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[+-]");

    // The number 1 is always needed for converting a 9's into a 10's complement
    // during negation, so we define it as a reusable constant
    private static final int[] NUMBER_ONE;

    static {
        // Initialise constant carrying array representation for number 1
        NUMBER_ONE = new int[ARRAY_LENGTH];
        NUMBER_ONE[ARRAY_LENGTH - 1] = 1;
    }

    public static String readConsoleInput(String prompt, Pattern validationPattern, String errorMessage) {
        String input = null;
        while (input == null) {
            System.out.print(prompt + ": ");
            if (INPUT_SCANNER.hasNext(validationPattern))
                input = INPUT_SCANNER.next(validationPattern);
            else {
                INPUT_SCANNER.nextLine();
                System.out.println(errorMessage);
            }
        }
        return input;
    }

    public static String getOperand(String operandName) {
        return readConsoleInput(
            "Operand " + operandName,
            INTEGER_PATTERN,
            "Illegal number format, please enter a positive/negative integer of max. " + MAX_NUMBER_LENGTH + " digits."
        );
    }

    private static String getOperator() {
        return readConsoleInput(
            "Arithmetical operator (+ or -)",
            OPERATOR_PATTERN,
            "Unknown operator, try again."
        );
    }

    public static int[] parseInteger(String number) {
        char sign = number.charAt(0);
        boolean isNegative = sign == '-' ? true : false;
        if (isNegative || sign == '+')
            number = number.substring(1);

        int[] result = new int[ARRAY_LENGTH];
        int parsePosition = number.length() - 1;
        for (int i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (parsePosition < 0)
                break;
            result[i] = number.charAt(parsePosition--) - '0';
        }
        return isNegative ? negate(result) : result;
    }

    public static int[] add(int[] operand1, int[] operand2) {
        int[] result = new int[ARRAY_LENGTH];
        int carry = 0;

        for (int i = ARRAY_LENGTH - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            result[i] = operand1[i] + operand2[i] + carry;
            if (result[i] >= 10) {
                result[i] = result[i] % 10;
                carry = 1;
            } else
                carry = 0;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static int[] complement(int[] operand) {
        int[] result = new int[ARRAY_LENGTH];

        for (int i = operand.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            result[i] = 9 - operand[i];
        return result;
    }

    public static int[] negate(int[] operand) {
        return add(complement(operand), NUMBER_ONE);
    }

    public static void print(int[] result, String operation) {
        System.out.print(operation.charAt(0) == '-' ? "Difference = " : "Sum = ");
        if (result[0] == 9) {
            result = negate(result);
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        boolean leadingZero = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (leadingZero) {
                if (result[i] == 0)
                    continue;
                leadingZero = false;
            }
            System.out.print(result[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(leadingZero ? "0" : "");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] operand1 = parseInteger(getOperand("#1"));
        int[] operand2 = parseInteger(getOperand("#2"));
        String operator = getOperator();

        if (operator.equals("-"))
            operand2 = negate(operand2);

        int[] result = new int[ARRAY_LENGTH];
        result = add(operand1, operand2);
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("Operand #1 = " + Arrays.toString(operand1));
            System.out.println("Operand #2 = " + Arrays.toString(operand2));
            System.out.println("Result     = " + Arrays.toString(result));
        }
        print(result, operator);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaimer:*** Your source code has multiple problems, but in order to keep it simple I am going to ignore most of them now and will just explain the reasons for your current problems and suggest fixes for them only.

If you check the array outputs from your `main` method, you see that the addition/subtraction results look good, i.e. the problem is not located in the calculation routines but in the print routine. There you have

- duplicate code: The `for` loops printing the positive/negative numbers are identical.
- a cosmetic problem: One leading zero is always printed.
- a logical error: You check for two consecutive zeroes in order to determine where leading zeroes end and the actual number begins. But you forget that

  - within a number there can also be duplicate zeroes, e.g. within 10098 or -9900. This explains why 10098 is printed as 1098: You are suppressing the first zero from being printed.
  - if there is a zero in the last array element (e.g. 9900) you cannot check the (non-existent) subsequent element without causing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. This explains why you get the exception for -9900.

Now what can/should you do?

- Eliminate the redundant `for` loop. You can use the same loop to print both positive and negative numbers.
- Use a `boolean` flag in order to remember if you are still looping through leading zeroes or not.

You can change your print method like so:

```java
public static void print(int[] result, String operation) {
    System.out.print(operation.charAt(0) == '-' ? "Difference = " : "Sum = ");
    if (result[0] == 9) {
        result = negate(result);
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    boolean leadingZero = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (leadingZero) {
            if (result[i] == 0)
                continue;
            leadingZero = false;
        }
        System.out.print(result[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(leadingZero ? "0" : "");
}
```

Comment: Great! It worked for the most part! But, I still have 2 small problems:
* first: when subtracting 342332 - 32, the result = 342299 || where it should be 342300
* second: what was the other problems you found in my code. Because I am still in learning process, and I would like to learn from experienced scientist like you to improve my programming skills.
thank you.

Comment: With all due respect: I am not a mentalist. How should I know that you have more problems if you are not explaining or even mentioning them? I had to revise your whole question text to make it more comprehensible because two others have complained about it.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, I pressed enter by mistake before I get to finish writing my comment.

Comment: Also, when subtracting 10 - 10, it will return nothing.

Comment: As for `result == 0`, the fix is simple. I updated the answer. The last statement should check the status of the `leadingZero` flag and print `"0"` in that case. As for 342332 - 32, I cannot reproduce your problem, the result is correct. Have you changed the code?

Comment: As for other problems, I really do not want to list them all here, let us stay on topic. Just one example: It is impossible to enter negative operands. In my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26844629/1082681) to your previous question I have showed you an easy way to parse integers, which you do not use here. But please, let us close this topic here, okay? This is a Q/A site, not a discussion forum. For your next problem, ask a new question. Or maybe learn some programming, read tutorials/books or just practice. I recommend test-driven programming (TDD), i.e. you can check your own results.

Comment: yes, I did change the code. I changed `System.out.print(operation.charAt(0) == '-' ? "Difference = " : "Sum = ");` to `if (operation.charAt(0) == '+')
      System.out.print("The subtotal of the two integers = ");
    if (operation.charAt(0) == '-')
      System.out.print("The subtraction of the two integers = ");` I believe it made something wrong, but not sure what exactly..

Comment: no it wasn't the problem. I figured it out. I will but the code down below for other users. Thank you much for your help. God bless you..

Comment: You figured out **nothing**. You have not even read my comment mentioning that I had updated my answer with for treating the zero result case long before you tried to fix it by obfuscating it.

Answer (score -1):

The code after fixing the problems. all thanks to @kriegaex !

```js
import java.util.*;
public class Program9 {

  public static String getOperand() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String stringOfInteger;
    
    System.out.print("Please enter an integer up to 50 numbers: ");
    stringOfInteger = scan.nextLine();
    return stringOfInteger;
  }

  public static int[] convert(String operand) {
    int [] integer = new int[50];
    char ch;
    
    int position = operand.length() - 1;
    for (int i = integer.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (position >= 0)
        ch = operand.charAt(position--);
      else
        ch = 0;
      if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
        integer[i] = ch - '0';
      } else {
        integer[i] = 0;
      }
    }
    return integer;
  }

  public static int[] add(int[] operand1, int[] operand2) {
    int [] result = new int[operand1.length];
    
    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = operand1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      result[i] = operand1[i] + operand2[i] + carry;
      if (result[i] / 10 == 1) {
        result[i] = result[i] % 10;
        carry = 1;
      } else
        carry = 0;
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static int[] complement(int[] operand2){
    int [] result = new int[operand2.length];
    
    for (int i = operand2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      result[i] = 9 - operand2[i];
    return result;
  }

  public static int[] add1(int[] operand2){
    int [] result = new int[operand2.length];
    
    result[operand2.length - 1] = 1;
    for (int i = result.length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
      result[i] = 0;
    return result;
  }

  public static int[] negate(int[] operand2){
    return add(add1(operand2), complement(operand2));
  }

  public static void print(int[] result, String operation) {
    if (operation.charAt(0) == '+')
      System.out.print("The subtotal of the two integers = ");
    else if (operation.charAt(0) == '-')
      System.out.print("The subtraction of the two integers = ");
    
    if (result[0] == 9) {
        result = negate(result);
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    boolean leadingZero = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (leadingZero) {
        if (result[i] == 0)
          continue;
        leadingZero = false;
      }
      System.out.print(result[i]);
    }
    if (leadingZero == true)
      System.out.println('0' - '0');
    System.out.println();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int [] result = new int[50];
    String string1 = getOperand();
    String string2 = getOperand();
    int [] integer1 = convert(string1);
    int [] integer2 = convert(string2);
    String operation;
    
    System.out.print("Please enter which operation will be used (+ or -): ");
    operation = scan.nextLine();
    if (operation.charAt(0) == '+')
      add(integer1, integer2);
    else if (operation.charAt(0) == '-')
      integer2 = negate(integer2);
    
    result = add(integer1, integer2);
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integer1));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integer2));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(add(integer1, integer2)));
    print(result, operation);
    
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is completely useless because it just repeats the original code plus my own bugfixes in `print(int[], String)`. Even worse, you took my bugfix `System.out.println(leadingZero ? "0" : "");` and obfuscated it into `if (leadingZero == true) System.out.println('0' - '0');`. Why the heck don't you just write `"0"` but `'0' - '0'`?!? I strongly suggest you delete your answer again because mine is the correct one. P.S.: Why do you format your code as Javascript? It is Java! You cannot "run the snippet" anyway.

Comment: The only things you changed from the original code was: (a) Rename method parameters from `operand` to `operand2` in methods which only have *one* operand, which is just obfuscation and makes absolutely no sense. (b) You use wrong mathematical terms in your text prompts which I had already fixed. The result of an addition is a *sum*, not a *subtotal*. The result of a subtraction is a *difference*, not the *subtraction* itself. Other than that and the obfuscating `'0' - '0'` you have not changed anything. Why do you not just copy and paste the full method from my answer and be fine?

Comment: Mr. @kriegaex, I appreciate your feedback, and your comments. I will try to answer your questions, and I apologize for making things complicated for you and other users. As I mentioned previously, I am still in the learning process, and this is actually my first semester in computer science. My lack of English is duo to my nationality. I am not a native speaker, which makes life a bit harder for me, especially when using mathematical terms in programming.

Comment: About the code, I did figure something out I made by mistake in the code that I was using in my laptop. However your code was working correctly. Also, I read your comments about leadingZeros and I did use them in my answer. I changed your bug-fix `System.out.println(leadingZero ? "0" : "");` because it seemed new to me as a beginner in programming. I also wanted to work more with if statements and make my program simple as much as possible.

Comment: I know it is not necessarily better, but I feel it is a good way to start learning from scratch, by not using other people codes and methods and try to understand programming better. I hope you understand why I made these changes, and I also would like you to know that I appreciate your concerns and I am so thankful.

Comment: one more thing, about using `'0' - '0'`, I know it seems ridicules, but I wanted to return `0` as an int instead of a string. I know it makes no difference in most cases, but I just wanted it to be more logic.. I guess

Comment: You are dealing with strings, not integers in that part of the code. But if you want to print an integer, why not just `System.out.println(0)` instead of subtracting characters(?!) in `System.out.println('0' - '0')`? It is totally unclear. This is obfuscation.

Comment: I repeat: Please delete this answer, it does not add any value.